# Unable to load shared library 'libsteam_api' with Facepunch Steamworks on linux

Tags: c#, shared-libraries, steamworks-api

I am trying to deploy a small Steamworks program to my server, however, when I try to build it for Linux I encounter `Unable to load shared library 'libsteam_api'`. I have included the `libsteam_api.so` file in the output directory `bin/Debug/net5.0` and linked it in my csproj

```
<Content Include=".\lib\libsteam_api.so">
   <Link>libsteam_api.so</Link>
   <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

Additionally while researching this issue I learned that a fix could be to put the libsteam_api file in `/usr/lib` however, this did not solve the issue for me. I am using C# net5.0, and the `Posix` version of Facepunch.Steamworks on Ubuntu.

The error message includes that I could try setting `LD_DEBUG`, however, the output after doing this contains no useful information.

```
     16545:     find library=libsteam_api.so [0]; searching
     16545:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     16545:      search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib:/usr/lib              (system search path)
     16545:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsteam_api.so
     16545:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsteam_api.so
     16545:       trying file=/lib/libsteam_api.so
     16545:       trying file=/usr/lib/libsteam_api.so
     16545:
     16545:     find library=liblibsteam_api.so [0]; searching
     16545:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     16545:      search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib:/usr/lib              (system search path)
     16545:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblibsteam_api.so
     16545:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblibsteam_api.so
     16545:       trying file=/lib/liblibsteam_api.so
     16545:       trying file=/usr/lib/liblibsteam_api.so
     16545:
     16545:     find library=libsteam_api [0]; searching
     16545:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     16545:      search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib:/usr/lib              (system search path)
     16545:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsteam_api
     16545:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsteam_api
     16545:       trying file=/lib/libsteam_api
     16545:       trying file=/usr/lib/libsteam_api
     16545:
     16545:     find library=liblibsteam_api [0]; searching
     16545:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     16545:      search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib:/usr/lib              (system search path)
     16545:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblibsteam_api
     16545:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblibsteam_api
     16545:       trying file=/lib/liblibsteam_api
     16545:       trying file=/usr/lib/liblibsteam_api
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple dumb mistakes caused this issue, for one I had at some point renamed the library from "libsteam_api.so" to "libst**r**eam_api", and I was attempting to run the 32-bit library rather than the 64 bit one. Fixing naming, and switching to the correct one fixed the issue for me.